# Static function inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, static, ecmascript-6

I've created a few classes as `Controllers` for my routes in `Node.js` and I'd like them to be able to work on a singleton basis (not required, it's an extra)

Main Controller class

```
class RouteController {

    static getInstance() {
        if (!RouteController.singleton) {
            RouteController.singleton = new RouteController();
        }

        return RouteController.singleton;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a route for example viewing posts and I want that class to have the singleton pattern as well, but not cop

PostController class

```
class PostController extends RouteController {

}
```

If I do this and check it `console.log(RouteController.getInstance() === PostController.getInstance())` it returns `true` when I want each (sub)class to have their own singleton instance.

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to see if your `singleton` property is an instance of `this`. This will work even if you call `RouteController.getInstance()` before doing so on any of the derived classes.

```js
class RouteController {
  log() {
    return 'Route';
  }
  static getInstance() {
    if (!(this.singleton instanceof this)) {
      // Only called twice so you can verify it's only initialized
      // once for each class
      console.log('Creating singleton...');
      this.singleton = new this();
    }
    return this.singleton;
  }
}

class PostController extends RouteController {
  log() {
    return 'Post';
  }
}

console.log(RouteController.getInstance().log());
console.log(PostController.getInstance().log());
console.log(RouteController.getInstance().log());
console.log(PostController.getInstance().log());
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal rules of functions apply. Hence you can use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside the function to refer to the object the method was invoked on (the constructor function itself in this case):

```
class RouteController {

    static getInstance() {
        if (!this.singleton) {
            this.singleton = new this();
        }

        return this.singleton;
    }
}
```

However, this will still not work if `RouteController.getInstance()` is called directly, because then all subclasses inherit a static `singleton` property, causing the `!this.singleton` test to fail for each subclass.

There are multiple ways to solve this. One would be to use `getOwnProperty` instead of accessing it directly:

```
if (!this.getOwnProperty('singleton')) {

}
```

Comment: I don't think you have access to `this` in static methods, do you?

Comment: @RobM.: Every function has a `this` value (except arrow functions). If you do `RouteController.getInstance()`, `this` refers to `RouteController`. Normal JavaScript, nothing magical here. After all, static methods are just properties on the function object. (`function RouteController() {}; RouteController.getInstance = function() {}`).

Comment: I should rephrase, I know there will be a `this` value, I just wasn't aware that it would refer to the class itself in a static method and am a bit surprised by that. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @RobM.: Depends on how the method is called of course, but if you do `Foo.bar()` as intended, `this` will refer to `Foo`.

Comment: Like @FelixKling says, `this` is useable, but no, it does not work.
`console.log("PostController singleton", PostController.getInstance());` shows the following in the console: `PostController singleton RouteController {}`

Comment: @CreasolDev: Ah... that would be because `RouteController` will already have a property `singleton`. I guess the question is will you ever call `RouteController.getSingleton()` directly? If yes, the fix is `if (!this.hasOwnPoperty('singleton'))`

Comment: Exactly, that is why I'm asking this question

Comment: @CreasolDev: How could have that been your question if you didn't use `this` before? O_o It works just fine if you don't call `RouteController.getSingleton()`: https://jsfiddle.net/k2o59kLn/

Comment: I meant the " Ah... that would be because RouteController will already have a property singleton."